# why Induction is Admissible?

Tags: induction

This question has been always intrigued me.
Why proof by Induction is admissible/acceptable ?
We use this type of proof nearly every where and some times
It's the easiest way of proof.

Comment: What do you mean?  Do you understand how induction works?  Or are you asking something else?

Comment: Have a look at (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/928323).

Comment: Are you using 'admissible' as a formal, defined term here?  If so, what definition?  If not, can you please further explain what you're asking for?

Comment: Bye_World, sorry, i've tried to look for it but probably not clearly enough.
any way, my question is why can we use induction as a valid proof indeed ? i can understand why it works Intuitively but i was sure why its valid.
i will try to check that post, i guess it being explained there why.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's admissible because it's defined as an axiom of our arithmetic. It was *chosen* as an axiom because it's a proof method that works - so much so that there are variants that apply even when you're *not* working with the natural numbers, as long as a few other properties hold.

If you have a problem with *why* it works, feel free to ask it and I can try to elaborate.

Comment: well i Intuitively understand why it works but i just keep missing the point
of why we can be sure its a valid way of proof, how do you know that for 
every set of proofs and theorems that being proven by Induction are valid ?
how do you know there isnt a theorem that cant be mistakly proven by induction ?

Comment: Because it's baked into the structure of the natural numbers and the way we are able to write statements of arithmetic. It happens to be equivalent to saying that the natural numbers are *well-ordered*, which is a specific property that has been assigned to them.

It's possible to pose a theorem that *appears* to be provable by induction, but where there is a fault in the proof, but the problem is in the misapplication of induction, not in induction itself.