# I would really appreciate some help solving this induction problem!!

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> $3.$ for all $n\ge1$, $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n(2i)^2=\frac{2n(2n+1)(2n+2)}{6}$

I have
$$\frac{2n(2n+1)(2n+2)(12(n+1)^2)}6= \frac{2n(2n+1)2(n+1)12(n+1)(n+1)}6.$$
I think I need to do something with the $(n+1)$.

However, I'm not sure where to go from here. I know the end goal is:
$$\frac{2(n+1)(2(n+1)+1)(2(n+1)+2)}6.$$

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can we use that $\Sigma_{i=1}^n i^2=\frac {n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$? If so $\Sigma_{i=1}^n (2i)^2=4\Sigma_{i=1}^n i^2=\frac {2n(2n+1)(2n+2)}6$ is easily found.

Comment: This is quite unclear, could you clarify, do you want a proof of this fact?

Comment: I just need to prove this using the principle of mathematical induction

Comment: If you are looking for a full solution, you can find many duplicates here. Did you searh for that? Otherwise let us know if you are looking for some insight to start with the solution.

Comment: To search for duplicates refer to the following [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265/505767)

Comment: As notice by Raptor you just need to prove $\Sigma_{k=1}^n k^2$ and then extend the resulf factoring out the $4$, then if you are just looking for an answer search for $\Sigma_{k=1}^n k^2$ + "induction".

Comment: @BillNgo If you need some more help to find the duplicates let us know. After you find that it would be fine if you delete that answer. Thanks

Comment: @BillNgo To avoid unpleasant downvoting and suddenly closure let us know your thought on that.

Comment: @gimusi That would be the case but my prof on the exam wants us to go through the whole induction process (base case, induction step,etc.). I set up the base case and am currently stuck on the induction step as you can see from my question. Perhaps I should of sent a picture of my work to avoid less confusion.

Comment: @BillNgo I mean that searching on MSE you can find many answers to the question. If you need that just search for it. Otherwise if you need something else you should clarify that!

Comment: @BillNgo Note that it is useless to give you full answer about the algebraic steps if you are confused on the method in general. Are you aware about induction works, what is the base case? what is the indutcion step? How did you obtain the expression you presented here?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

The best way is what indicated by Raptors in the comments that is

$$\Sigma_{i=1}^n i^2=\frac {n(n+1)(2n+1)}6 \implies \Sigma_{i=1}^n (2i)^2=4\Sigma_{i=1}^n i^2=\frac {2n(2n+1)(2n+2)}6$$

then it suffices to prove by induction the LHS as explained in many duplicates you can find on the site as for example here

- [Sum of First $n$ Squares Equals $\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/48080/505767)

For a general insight about the method we are applying refer to

- [proof by induction - explanation on it](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/928323/505767)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof by weak induction.

The idea is to prove the statement for the smallest natural number possible, and then prove it for every number after that. Imagine climbing a ladder. You start at the bottom step and you have to walk up every step after that to get to the top.

Let $P(n)$ be $$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (2i)^2 = \frac{2n(2n+1)(2n+2)}{6}$$

Step one is the Base Case: Choose n = 1 because the summation formula starts at i = 1, so it doesn't make sense to start at 0 or a larger natural number.

I. BASE CASE, $P(1):$ $$\sum_{i = 1}^{1} (2i)^2 = 2(1)^2 = \frac{2(1)(2(1)+1)(2(1)+2)}{6} = 2$$

Next is the assumption step, choose a variable that hasn't been used for clarity.

II. Assume $P(j):$ $$\sum_{i = 1}^{j} (2i)^2 = \frac{2j(2j+1)(2j+2)}{6}$$

Now it must be shown that the statement is true for all following natural numbers. To help guide you write out $P(j+1)$. THIS DOES NOT PROVE ANYTHING. It is just a roadmap to help guide you through the problem.

$(*)$ $$\sum_{i = 1}^{j+1} (2i)^2 = \frac{2(j+1)(2(j+1)+1)(2(j+1)+2)}{6}$$

Here is the actual final step:

III. Show $P(j+1):$

$$\sum_{i = 1}^{j+1} (2i)^2 = [\sum_{i = 1}^{j} (2i)^2 ] + 4(j+1)^2$$
The following line is where we use the inductive hypothesis. What that means is that we use the assumption $P(j)$ to prove $P(j+1)$. When equal signs are involved this means making a substitution. 
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{j+1} (2i)^2 = [\frac{2j(2j+1)(2j+2)}{6} ] + 4j^2+8j+4$$
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{j+1} (2i)^2 = [\frac{(8j^3+12j^2+4j)}{6} ] + \frac{24j^2+48j+24}{6}$$
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{j+1} (2i)^2 = \frac{8j^3+36j^2+52j+24}{6}$$

At this point you can use synthetic division to factor the right hand side, but I'll leave that to you.

$$\sum_{i = 1}^{j+1} (2i)^2 = \frac{2(j+1)(2(j+1)+1)(2(j+1)+2)}{6}$$

You then end the proof by weak induction with the following statement:
$P(1)$ and $P(k+1)$ are true, therefore $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}($$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (2i)^2 = \frac{2n(2n+1)(2n+2)}{6})$

Comment: For the Induction step I usually denote $\sum_{i = 1}^{j} (2i)^2 = \frac{2j(2j+1)(2j+2)}{6}$ as the "induction hypotesis" and $\sum_{i = 1}^{j+1} (2i)^2 = \frac{2(j+1)(2(j+1)+1)(2(j+1)+2)}{6}$ as the thesis we need to prove using the hypotesis. It seems a very good explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you got
$$
\frac{2n(2n+1)(2n+2)(12(n+1)^2)}{6}
$$
from. It should be
$$
\frac{2n(2n+1)(2n+2)\color{red}{+}12(n+1)^2}{6}
$$
and with this fix you should be able to finish up.

---

However, it's better if you do some simplifications, to get rid of useless factors.

The induction step consists in writing
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(2i)^2=
\sum_{i=1}^{n}(2i)^2+(2(n+1))^2
$$
and substituting the summation with the formula provided by the induction hypothesis, so to get
$$
\frac{2n(2n+1)(2n+2)}{6}+4(n+1)^2
$$

Your goal is to prove that this equals
$$
\frac{2(n+1)(2(n+1)+1)(2(n+1)+2)}{6}=
\frac{2(n+1)(2n+3)(n+2)}{3}
$$
which you obtain from the formula to prove by changing $n$ into $n+1$, which you seem to have done right.

Consider
\begin{align}
\frac{2n(2n+1)(2n+2)}{6}+4(n+1)^2
&=\frac{2n(2n+1)(n+1)}{3}+4(n+1)^2 \\[4px]
&=\frac{2}{3}(n+1)\bigl(n(2n+1)+6(n+1)\bigr) \\[4px]
&=\frac{2}{3}(n+1)(2n^2+7n+6)
\end{align}
Since $2n^2+7n+6=(n+2)(2n+3)$, you're done.

Comment: I'm not sure that it will help the asker to clarify the doubts on the application of the method. What about the base case and the induction step?

Comment: @gimusi The OP did some mistake, from the text in the question, he/she already has done some work in that direction.

Comment: That's could be a correct interpretation. I've asket to add some more detail in order to identify better his/her doubts.

Answer (score 0):

So to prove this we must use induction and  since the LHS is a sum, we add $(2(n+1))^2$.
We do this because if $n$ and $n+1$ every natural number works as $n$ is arbitrary. Therefore, we only need to prove it works for $n+1$.
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(2i)^2=\frac{2n(2n+1)(2n+2)}{6}+(2(n+1))^2$$
This gives:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(2i)^2=\frac{(4n^2+14n+12)(2n+2)}{6}$$
$4n^2+14n+12$ factors to give:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(2i)^2=\frac{(2n+3)(2n+4)(2n+2)}{6}$$
Therefore:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(2i)^2=\frac{(2(n+1)+2)(2(n+1)+1)(2(n+1))}{6}$$
All that remains is to check the "base-case" when $n=1$.
This will complete the proof.

Comment: I'm not sure that it will help the asker to clarify the doubts on the application of the method. What about the base case and the induction step?

Comment: I assumed he knew induction and just needed to know how to go to $n+1$.

Comment: I think you should revise your assumption, when I read "I think I need to do something with the (n+1)" I suppose that the asker is really confused about induction. I really think we are not helping the asker with such kind of answers.

Comment: I suppose that you are correct.

Comment: I see where I messed up I was supposed to add 2(n+1)^2 but I multiplied it on accident.

Comment: It is good that you were able to identify your error to come to grips with induction.

Comment: @BillNgo It would be also fine if you could add your full work here in order to understand what exactly your doubts are. In that way we could help you in a more effective way.